# Unable to add second external monitor on M1 MacBookPro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

I have a M1 MacBook Pro 13" running on latest macOS Monterey.
I have two external monitors (HDMI & Display Port) and I can use only one of them at a time. Am using the standard USB C to HDMI adapter to connect to both USB C ports.

When I connect the second one it just simply does not detect. Tried Settings -> Displays -> (Opt) Detect Displays as well.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: did you try to close the macbook lid? It may support only 2 screens at once.

Comment: M1 Macs only support one external screen. Unless you use something like DisplayLink you will be out of luck,

Comment: Damn that's a huge bummer that it only supports one display, glad its just an office asset.